# Guidance on Mary L. Boas, Probability & Statistics, Section 4, Problem 20

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

The problem 20.a asks to prove that the modified Polya urn process described in Example 5 leads to Bose Einstein Statistics.

Then problem 20.b asks to prove the modified polya url process yields MB and FD statistics if the cards are replaced and not replaced respectively.

I am sure of the derivation of 20.a below (i.e. $P_{Bose-Einstein}$). Can someone please help checking the remaining 2 (i.e. $P_{Maxwell-Boltzmann}$ and $P_{Fermi-Dirac}$).

$N = \sum\limits_{i =1}^nN_i$

$P_{Bose-Einstein} = \bigg[\frac{1}{n}\frac{2}{n+1}...\frac{N_1}{n+N_1-1}\bigg].\bigg[\frac{1}{n+N_1}\frac{2}{n+N_1+1}...\frac{N_2}{n+N_1+N_2-1}\bigg]...\bigg[\frac{1}{n+N_1+N_2..N_{n-1}}\frac{2}{n+N_1+N_2..N_{n-1}+1}...\frac{N_n}{n+N_1+N_2..N_{n-1}+(N_{n}-1)}\bigg].\frac{N!}{N_1!.N_2!...N_n!} = \frac{N!}{P(n+N-1,n-1)} = \frac{1}{C(n+N-1, N)}$

$P_{Maxwell-Boltzmann} = \big[\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}...\frac{1}{n}\big].\frac{N!}{N_1!.N_2!...N_n!} = \frac{N!}{n^N.N_1!N_2!...N_n!}$

$P_{Fermi-Dirac} = \big[\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{(n-1)}...\frac{1}{(n-(N_1+N_2..N_{n-1}+N_{n}-1))}\big].\frac{N!}{N_1!.N_2!...N_n!} = \frac{N!}{\frac{n!}{(n-N)!}} = \frac{1}{C(n, N)}$ (since $N_i \in \{0,1\}$)

=== Here is the Section 4, Problem 20 ===

> 20. (a) In Example 5, a mathematical model is discussed which claims to give a dis- tribution of identical balls into boxes in such a way that all distinguishable arrangements are equally probable (Bose-Einstein statistics). Prove this by showing that the probability of a distribution of N balls into n boxes (accord- ing to this model) with N1 balls in the first box, N2 in the secoPnd, · · · , Nn in the nth, is 1/C(n−1+N, N) for any set of numbers Ni such that ni=1 Ni = N.
>
> (b) Show that the model in (a) leads to Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics if the drawn card is replaced (but no extra card added) and to Fermi-Dirac statistics if the drawn card is not replaced. Hint: Calculate in each case the number of possible arrangements of the balls in the boxes. First do the problem of 4 particles in 6 boxes as in the example, and then do N particles in n boxes (n > N) to get the results in Problem 19.

==== Here is the referred Example 5 =====

> Example 5. In Example 4 we found the same answer for the probability that two partic-
>   ular boxes were empty whether or not we considered the balls distinguishable. This
>   was true because the allowed distinguishable arrangements were equally probable.
>   Without the restriction of one ball or none per box, all distinguishable arrangements
>   are not equally probable according to the methods of Examples 3 and 4. For exam-
>   ple, the probability of all balls in box 1 is 1/64; compare this with the probability
>   of no balls in the first 2 boxes and one ball in each of the other 4 boxes, which is
>    4! ÷ 64 = 1 . We see that the concentrated arrangements (all or several balls in one 54
>    box) are less probable than the more uniform arrangements.
>   Now we are going to try to imagine a situation in which all distinguishable ar-
>   rangements are equally probable. Suppose the 6 boxes are benches in a waiting room
>   and the 4 balls are people who are going to come in and sit on the benches. Then
>   if the people are friends, there will be a certain tendency for them to sit together
>   and the probabilities we have been calculating will not apply—the probabilities of
>   the concentrated arrangements will increase. Consider the following mathematical
>   model. (This is a modification of P ́olya’s urn model.) We have 6 boxes labeled 1
>   to 6, and 4 balls. From 6 cards labeled 1 to 6 we draw one at random and place a
>   ball in the box numbered the same as the card drawn. We then replace the card and
>   also add another card of the same number so that there are now 7 cards, two with
>   the number first drawn. We now select a card at random from these 7, put a ball
>   in the corresponding box and again replace the card adding a duplicate to make
>   8 cards. We repeat this process two more times (until all balls are distributed).
>   Then the probability that all balls are in box 1 is 1 · 2 · 3 · 4. The probability 6789
>       ofoneballineachofthefirst4boxesis 1 ·1 ·1 ·1 ·4!(here 1 ·1 ·1 ·1 isthe 6789 6789
>           probability that the first ball is in box 1, the second in box 2, etc.; we must add to this the probability that the first ball is in box 3, the second in box 1, etc.; there are 4! such possibilities all giving one ball in each of the first 4 boxes). We see that the distributions “all balls in box 1” and “one ball in each of the first 4 boxes” are equally probable. Further calculation (Problem 20) shows that all distinguishable arrangements are equally probable.

Comment: I don't have the book. Can you write these exercises and examples in full?

Comment: Problem 20 and Example5, pasted above.

Comment: Fixed a mistake in $P_{Fermi-Dirac}$. It now makes more sense than before. It would be great to get the above double checked.